# Delete empty folders in r

Tags: r, unzip

I have list of zipped files with text files in a directory which contains empty folders in between. I want to unzip the files and after unzip want to delete the empty folders if exists. Need help in doing this in R.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `list.files(include.dirs=TRUE)` to get a list of files and directories, then use `file.info` to check if this is a directory. Since `file.info` is showing 0 for size when it is a directory, you need to list all the files inside the directory and get the size to check if its empty. Then you can delete the directory if the size is 0 using `unlink`:

```
lapply(list.files(include.dirs=TRUE, full.names=TRUE), function(x) {
    fi <- file.info(x)
    if (fi$isdir) {
        f <- list.files(x, all.files=TRUE, recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
        sz <- sum(file.info(f)$size)

        #as precaution, print to make sure before using unlink(x, TRUE)
        if (sz==0L) print(x)   
    }
})
```

Comment: It is best to rely on the number of files, not the sum of file sizes. `file.create('foo.txt')` for example creates a file with size 0. If the goal is to delete directories without files in them, then why not do just that. Just replace `sz <- sum...` with `nfiles <- length(f)`, and make the decision based on `nfiles == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `icesTAF::remdir(path, recursive = T)` to delete empty folders.

```
for i in 1:[your folders count]{
 icesTAF::rmdir(list.files([your path containing folders], full.names = T)[i], recursive = T)
}
```